# composite of functions partial derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

I want example that the composite of functions whose partial derivatives exist may fail to have partial derivatives, and the composite of functions whose directional derivatives exist may fail to have directional derivatives. For first argument maybe we should consider some functions like $$x^my^n/x^a+y^c$$ but I dont know how exactly should I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ to be $f(x,0)=(x,x),$ $f(0,y)=(-y,y),$ and $f=(0,0)$ elsewhere. Then $f_x (0,0)=(1,1),$ and $f_y (0,0)=(-1,1).$

Define $g:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ to be $0$ on the axes, and $(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$ elsewhere. Then $g_x (0,0)=0,$ and $g_y (0,0)=0.$

Then

$$(g\circ f)(x,0)=(2x^2)^{1/2}=\sqrt 2 |x|,$$

hence $(g\circ f)_x(0,0)$ does not exist. Same idea for $(g\circ f)_y(0,0).$